# Min-Max Sum, given 5 ints find min sum and max sum

Tags: java, arrays, sum, arr, minmax

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Example

arr = [1,3,5,7,9]

The minimum sum is 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16 and the maximum sum is 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 24. The function prints

16 24

Basically, add the array each time excluding one element and check which is the min and max sum.

```
class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'miniMaxSum' function below.
     *
     * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
     */

    public static void miniMaxSum(List<Integer> arr) {
    // Write your code here
        //initialize min and max sum
        int minsum = 0;
        int maxsum = 0;
        int minVal = arr.get(0);
        int maxVal = arr.get(0);
        
        //sum of minsum
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
           if(arr.get(i) > maxVal){
               maxVal = arr.get(i);
           }
            minsum += arr.get(i);
        }
        minsum= minsum - maxVal;
        
        //sum for maxsum
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            if(arr.get(i) < minVal){
                minVal = arr.get(i);
            }
            maxsum += arr.get(i);   
        } 
        maxsum = maxsum - minVal;
        
        //prints out results
        System.out.println(minsum + " " + maxsum);
        
    }

}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        List<Integer> arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(toList());

        Result.miniMaxSum(arr);

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
[first two results say they are correct then it says 10/15 failed][1]
```

Comment: I was able to solve it using longs instead of ints!!

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this of class Result:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Result {

  public static void miniMaxSum(List<Integer> arr) {
    // Write your code here
    //initialize min and max sum
    int minsum = 0;
    int maxsum = 0;
    int minVal = Collections.max(arr);
    int maxVal = Collections.min(arr);
    int sum = sum(arr);

    minsum = sum - maxVal;
    maxsum = sum - minVal;

    //prints out results
    System.out.println(minsum + " " + maxsum);

  }

  private static int sum(List<Integer> array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int value : array) {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

}

Comment: had the same results ;-;